# Parse string with sscanf

Tags: c

I have an access log as below:

```
[Thu Oct  4 00:20:05.140 2018] 0.017 sec 0.017 sec [ext2/0/rel 53798 (0,10)] [question_description] @products_description"find ea"/1
```

I need to read datetime [Thu Oct  4 00:20:05.140 2018] and a string in between "find ea".

My code:

```
int main(void) {
  char buffer[10000];
  int count = 0;
  char datetime[35];
  FILE* fptr;
  fptr = fopen("query.log", "r");
  while (count < 10) {
    if (!fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fptr)) break;

    sscanf(buffer,"%[^\n]", datetime);
    printf("date : %s", datetime);

    count++;
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I need to update the expression for `sscanf` so that I can get datetime and string "xxxx"

Comment: Sorry, this is not free code-writing service. You need to show us your efforts and ask specific questions for specific problems you are having.

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE]. [Edit] your post to add and MCVE.

Comment: Please see my code above

Comment: Ok, so what's wrong with it? Provide sample input and output. Explain what you think is broken or where you are stuck.

Comment: My code prints the entire row of the log instead of the datetime.

Comment: As it stands, `sscanf` gets the whole line: as you say. Look for the first `[` and the first `]` and extract what is between them. Start by printing the index of those brackets, and go step by step.

Comment: what is the regular express to extract between [ and ]

Comment: C does not have a regular expression for that.

Comment: `sscanf(buffer,"%[^\n]", datetime);` scans too much into `datetime` overwriting its array bounds --> UB.  Certainly something like `sscanf(buffer,"[%34[^]]", datetime);` is needed.

Comment: Fawad. 1) Please explain "read ... a string in between "find ea".".  2) Explain 'so that I can get ... string "xxxx""  3) What exactly is expected as output?  4) What should happen if the input is in an unexpected format?

Comment: The notation `%[…]` is a scan set; it is only very loosely related to a regex.  It only supports a subset of the character class notation from regexes.  See POSIX [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) — it has some extensions over standard C, but they're clearly documented.

Comment: Bottom line: this is not a good job for `sscanf`. `strtok` might work. Or `strchr`, `strrchr`, and `strstr`. Or just a plain old `for` loop to go through the characters one by one. In other words, I would write a simple, ad hoc parser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use strtok to get the desired strings, here's my solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
 {
  char * tok;
  char buffer[10000];
  int count = 0;
  char datetime[35];
  char qdescription[35];
  char pdescription[35];
  FILE* fptr;

  if(!(fptr = fopen("query.log", "r")))
  {
    perror("No file\n");
    fclose(fptr);
    return -1;
  }

while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fptr))
{
  for(tok = strtok(buffer, "[]"); tok != NULL; tok = strtok(NULL, "[]"), count++)
  {
    switch(count)
    {
      case 0: strcpy(datetime, tok);

      case 4: strcpy(qdescription, tok);

      case 5: strcpy(pdescription, tok);
    } 
  }
}

printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", datetime, qdescription, pdescription);

  return 0;
}
```

with this code you can retrieve the date and the `question_description`, i wasn't able to isolate the last `product_description`, see if you can find a workaround to this problem.